# iOS: Single Finger rotation and translation of an image

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitouch

Currently i am following this [Link](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer) to perform Single finger rotation on an image and its working fine.But i am wondering after performing rotation, how to perform translation operation if i want to move the image from one postion of screen to any other position.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   // We can look at any touch object since we know we 
   // have only 1. If there were more than 1 then 
   // touchesBegan:withEvent: would have failed the recognizer.
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

   // A tap can have slight movement, but we're not interested
   // in a tap. We want more movement. So if a tap is detected
   // fail the recognizer. 
   if ([self state] == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible) {
      [self setState:UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan];
   } else {
      [self setState:UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged];
   }

   // To rotate with one finger, we simulate a second finger.
   // The second figure is on the opposite side of the virtual
   // circle that represents the rotation gesture.

   UIView *view = [self view];
   CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX([view bounds]), CGRectGetMidY([view bounds]));
   CGPoint currentTouchPoint = [touch locationInView:view];
   CGPoint previousTouchPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:view];

   // use the movement of the touch to decide
   // how much to rotate the carousel
   CGPoint line2Start = currentTouchPoint;
   CGPoint line1Start = previousTouchPoint;
   CGPoint line2End = CGPointMake(center.x + (center.x - line2Start.x), center.y + (center.y - line2Start.y));
   CGPoint line1End = CGPointMake(center.x + (center.x - line1Start.x), center.y + (center.y - line1Start.y));

   //////
   // Calculate the angle in radians.
   // (From: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/12/better-two-finger-rotate-gesture.html )
   CGFloat a = line1End.x - line1Start.x;
    CGFloat b = line1End.y - line1Start.y;
    CGFloat c = line2End.x - line2Start.x;
    CGFloat d = line2End.y - line2Start.y;

   CGFloat line1Slope = (line1End.y - line1Start.y) / (line1End.x - line1Start.x);
   CGFloat line2Slope = (line2End.y - line2Start.y) / (line2End.x - line2Start.x);

    CGFloat degs = acosf(((a*c) + (b*d)) / ((sqrt(a*a + b*b)) * (sqrt(c*c + d*d))));

   CGFloat angleInRadians = (line2Slope > line1Slope) ? degs : -degs;
   //////

   [self setRotation:angleInRadians];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that my answer will help you, but I fear that you cannot do "one-touch" rotation and "one-touch" translation at the same time. Indeed, your code always interprets a single touch as for rotation, by "simulating" the presence of a second finger touching the display.

What you could do is trying and differentiate two single-finger gestures so to associate one with rotation and the other with translation. For example, the gesture for translation could be a "long touch" (i.e., you touch and keep touching for some time, then you move the object).

Hope this helps, anyway...

Comment: But the image i am currently using is of size 30*30 which is project requirement.On which if i perform double finger rotation it is not happening properly.So what i can do, Any suggestion or any pointer?

Comment: the only thing I can come out is what I said: you press (say, half a second) and then drag the image; or, you swipe to rotate it. Seems pretty consistent and should work fine with a 30x30 image...

Comment: For long press you mean UILongPressGestureRecognizer or i have to implement it in UITouch event method..

Comment: For moving the image i have previously implemented following - (void)translate:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    if ((gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) ||(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded))
    {
      self.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.transform, translation.x, translation.y);
     [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self];

    } but while dragging my image it goes outside the boundary So how can i fix it

Comment: I think that by doing: `self.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.transform...` you are accumulating the translation (you keep adding translation to the same translation matrix, so to say). Try instead using `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation`, so each time you apply a new translation. Just a guess...